# Querying queues locally throws an exception

Tags: msmq

I'm trying to query my local queues on my machine, with the follow code:

```
var c = new MessageQueueCriteria();
c.MachineName = Environment.MachineName;
var queues = MessageQueue.GetMessageQueueEnumerator(c);
```

but the code throws an exception on the second line complaining:

A workgroup installation computer does not support the operation.

Stack trace:    at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.GetMachineId(String machineName)
   at System.Messaging.MessageQueueCriteria.set_MachineName(String value)

and the MessageQueueErrorCode enum is set to System.Messaging.MessageQueueErrorCode.UnsupportedOperation.

The strange thing is I am on a domain and not a workgroup! and other application (QueueExplorer) seem to work file. Any ideas how I can get around it?

Update: Seems the error comes from running this piece of code that is in the setter of the property, not sure how to fix it though.

```
new MessageQueuePermission(MessageQueuePermissionAccess.Browse, "*").Demand();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class **MessageQueueCriteria** is used to filter **PUBLIC** message queues when using the **GetPublicQueues** method. To be able to browse for public queues you must enable the **MSMQ Active Directory Services Integration** feature. If your computer is joined to a domain is not enough.

If you would like to browse your local **PRIVATE** queues you should use:

```
MessageQueue[] queues = MessageQueue.GetPrivateQueuesByMachine(Environment.MachineName);
```